# Difference between arguments with and without quotes for a Perl script in csh

Tags: csh

Is there a difference between arguments with and without quotes for a Perl script?

Eg. `myscript -option "SomeValue"` vs `myscript -option SomeValue`

The shell is csh

Comment: That depends on your shell. Look for ‘quoting’ or something similar in its manual.

Comment: edited  and added csh as shell after @Biffen comment. In csh they are behaving in a similar fashion.

Comment: If the arguments only alpha-numeric than there is no difference. But if the arguments contains -- for example space, e.g.: -option "Some Value" then it will be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the argument has space, then while parsing, if the srgument is in quotes, the entire value will be picked up while using `$ARGV[$i]` where `$i` refers to the position of the argument. Else the value only up to the first space will be picked up.